# Template specialization for the base template type for future derived types

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have a class that works as wrapper for some primitives or custom types. I want to write explicit specialization for custom template type.
My code that reproduces the problem:

```
template < class T >
struct A {
    void func() { std::cout << "base\n"; }
};

template <>
struct A<int> {};

template < class T, class CRTP >
struct BaseCrtp {
    void someFunc() {
        CRTP::someStaticFunc();
    }
};

struct DerrType : BaseCrtp<int, DerrType> {
    static void someStaticFunc() {}
};

template < class T, class CRTP >
struct A< BaseCrtp<T, CRTP> > {
    void func() { std::cout << "sometype\n"; }
};

int main() {
    A<DerrType> a;
    a.func(); // print: "base". should be: "sometype"

    return 0;
}
```

`A<DerrType>` use default function, not a specialization. How can I make specialization for these set of classes?
I will have a lot of types like `DerrType`, and I want to make common behavior for all of them.
`DerrType` and others will be used as *curiously recurring template pattern*

Comment: Template specializations don't work this way. Unlike _overloaded functions_ where argument types could undergo a myriad forms of conversions for overload resolution, selection of _class-template specialization_ do not do this. `DerrType != BaseCrtp<T, CRTP>`

Comment: To buttress my previous comment, if you change `A<DerrType> a;` to `A<BaseCrtp<int, DerrType>> a;`, you see it works as you expected. So what you want to do is to coerce the type system into preferring your specialization either by a _concept_ or by an indirection.

Comment: You are right. But I wanted to find the right way for it. I have already got the right answer from user17732522

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I fully understood what you want, but maybe something like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept DerivedFromBaseCrtp = requires(T& t) {
    []<typename U, typename CRTP>(BaseCrtp<U, CRTP>&){}(t);
};

template < DerivedFromBaseCrtp T >
struct A<T> {
    void func() { std::cout << "sometype\n"; }
};
```

The concept basically checks whether `T` is equal to or is publicly inherited (directly or indirectly) from some specialization of `BaseCrtp`. Otherwise the call to the lambda would be ill-formed. Template argument deduction only succeeds in the call if the argument and parameter type match exactly or the argument has a derived type of the parameter. If the class is inherited non-publicly, the reference in the call can't bind to the parameter.

The concept will however fail if the type is inherited from *multiple* `BaseCrtp` specializations, in which case template argument deduction on the call will not be able to choose between the multiple choices.

---

Alternatively you can also use the stricter concept

```
template<typename T>
concept CrtpDerivedFromBaseCrtp = requires(T& t) {
    []<typename U>(BaseCrtp<U, T>&){}(t);
};
```

which will also require that the type `T` is actually using the CRTP pattern on `BaseCrtp` (directly or through a some base class between `BaseCrtp` and `T`). Again, this will fail if `T` is inherited multiple times from some `BaseCrtp<U, T>` specialization, although it will ignore specializations with a type other than `T` in the second position.

---

For another alternative you might want to check that `T` is derived from some type `X` such that `X` is derived from `BaseCrtp<U, X>` for some `U` (meaning that `X` uses the CRTP pattern correctly). That could be done using this variation:

```
template <typename T>
concept CrtpDerivedFromBaseCrtp =
    requires(T& t) {
        []<typename U, typename CRTP>(BaseCrtp<U, CRTP>&)
            requires(std::is_base_of_v<CRTP, T> &&
                     std::is_base_of_v<BaseCrtp<U, CRTP>, CRTP>)
        {}
        (t);
    };
```

Again, this fails if `T` is derived from multiple `BaseCrtp` specializations, directly or indirectly.

Comment: I'd add a requirement that `BaseCrtp<U, T>` is a base of `T` as well (in the lambda)?  I guess it can't deduce `U` without it being a base class, so it is safe without it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That was my intention with the alternative version. It tests that `BaseCrtp<U, T>` is a base of `T` for some `U` (with the same limitations as the first version). Otherwise deduction of `U` will fail.